# Protecting a comparator in a tension measurement device

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, switches, comparator

I am building a device to measure the tension of a conducting wire using an Arduino.

The basic circuit concept consists of two stages:

1. The wire is placed in a strong magnetic field. Then the Arduino send a 2 seconds saw-tooth pulse going up to 24V through the wire which cause it to vibrate in its fundamental frequency ranging around 60-200 Hz.
2. Since the wire is now vibrating in a magnetic field, it produces an induced AC EMF with the same vibration frequency. The voltage on the wire is amplified using a comparator which sends a square wave back to the Arduino where the frequency is measured. Calculating the tension from the fundamental frequency is then very simple to do.

A more detailed schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOVvEh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am looking for a way to protect the 5V comparator from the 24V pulse going through the wire that will not affect my ability to measure the induced voltage later on.

An Ideal solution would be a way to switch the system from the "pulse stage" to the "measure stage", each time disconnecting the unnecessary part of the circuit. I was thinking of achieving that using a MOSFET switch but got it all messed up. I did manage to pull it off with a mechanical relay disconnecting the comparator but I  rather find a different solution.

Note that this is an individual device that will not be mass produced, so a solution does not have to be cost efficient.

This is my first circuit I ever design and my first time asking for help on StackExchange so if there is anything unclear please tell and I'll be happy to explain some more.

Comment: Why not put the pulse through a transformer and TVS before comparing?

Comment: You could choose from, at least, three approaches: A. protect the comparator input from the 24V 'excitation' signal so that it can stay in circuit all the time, or B. isolate the comparator input while pulses are being applied, or C. both A and B. Option C seems to be most robust, and gives more options for B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MAX913](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX912-MAX913.pdf) has a fairly high input bias current (8uA maximum) so it won't tolerate too much series resistance in the input before you start to see significant errors. Even 1000 ohms can cause more than 5mV offset.

A series resistor of maybe 500 ohms and back-to-back (inverse parallel) Schottky diodes (eg. [1N5817](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/1N/1N5817.pdf)) across the input may work for you. Presumably the signal from the wire is less than a couple hundred mV (if not you'll be exceeding the input CM range of the comparator and also you'd get some damping of the wire with this configuration). Add another 100 ohms from the diodes to the input if you feel paranoid. Also a matching resistance of about 500 or 600 ohms respectively from the inverting input to ground to match off the offsets due to bias current.

Edit: We also need to consider the resistance of the wire, so the resistance should be 510 + 100 + 200 ohms in this case, or 810 ohms.

The input bias current of the comparator can be as much as 8uA from each input, but the *difference* between the two currents is tightly matched.. only 300nA at room temperature typical and 1uA worst case over temperature. That means that if we match the resistance, the offset due to the bias current will only be 0.24mV typical and 0.8mV maximum worst case. Since the comparator itself has an offset of 0.1mV typical and 3mV maximum worst case, it doesn't change things much.

Eg:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXFLlB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Let me check if I get it right: R1 is there to limit the current that will flow through D1 while the pulse is high. But since the comparator has input bias current of 8uA it also means the induced signal will have about 4.8mV voltage drop when measeaured (8uA*(R1+R2)). I am not sure how strong the signal is but I suppose I can find a comparator with lower input bias current if needed. Increasing R1 would mean less power dissipated and also less current drawn from the source. What is the purpose of R2, D2 and R3? is there any reason the resistance near both inputs must be the same?

Comment: D2 protects the input if the wire rings below zero. Don't leave it out- if it goes more than a couple hundred mV negative bad things can happen. R2 keeps the current low into the input parasitic diode even if the voltage goes quite negative at D2. R3 gets rid of most of the offset. The input offset current of the chip is typically only 300nA. But I didn't consider the wire resistance  and I'll correct that with an edit an explain above.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest clamp diodes, a DC blocking cap, and a series resistor.  The clamp diodes would be connected between the input pin of the comparator and both voltage rails, this prevents the voltage on the input pin from exceeding the voltage on the power rails.  Then add a series resistor to limit the current that can flow through the diodes when the voltage tries to exceed the rails.  Then you should add a parallel resistor to the comparator reference voltage.  Then add a decently sized DC blocking cap.  The idea is to get the oscillation centered around the comparator reference voltage so it will trigger nicely on the edges.  Size the resistors so they don't attenuate the signal too much, but provide a decent current limit.  Size the capacitor so it will not reduce the bandwidth below what you're trying to measure.